# Recommended Linker Behavior for .NET MAUI App (Release)

Tags: maui

I wanted to deploy my .NET MAUI App to my iPhone with **VS 2022 - 17.8 - Preview 5 (.NET 7)** in **Release**-Mode. Xcode version is 14.2 and I can't upgrade, unfortunately.

Unfortunately, I get this error all the time:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Below you see my settings, but I am still faced with this error message.

What is the recommended Linker Behavior I should use in my App Properties?

[image]

Comment: if the Linker options aren't working, you either need to update XCode or downgrade Microsoft iOS to a compatible version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error prompt, you can first set the `linker behaviour` to `Link Framework SDKs Only`.

The steps are :
Right click on the iOS project and select Properties.
In the `Properties` Window,
[image]

Under `iOS Build` section, select `Link Framework SDKs Only` for Linker Behavior.

That'll set the managed linker behaviour to `Link Framework SDKs Only`.

And just as Jason mentioned, if the `Linker options` aren't working, you either need to update XCode or downgrade Microsoft iOS to a compatible version.

Comment: Yes, but strange thing was that it also mentioned „Link Framework SDKs Only“ even it was already set. But, after deleting a couple of times on Mac and local obj/bin, re-starting connection to Mac, it worked with this setting again